# Managing .NET project with Maven

Tags: .net, maven-2

I am new to Maven, but I'm trying to use it to manage a .NET project. I am using the command

```
mvn dotnet:compile
```

but this is the error that I am getting

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Please add the executable for build to your path
```

I've searched for this error, but it doesn't seem to be well documented. I hope for some suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be because

- the [pre-requisites](http://maven-dotnet-plugin.appspot.com/usage.html) for the plugin are not installed
- [path to the installation](http://maven-dotnet-plugin.appspot.com/settings.html) of .Net is not provided.

Comment: Hello,

Both of the above conditions were satisfied. My settings.xml file had the correct paths to all of the pre-requisite applications. Also the paths to the .NET frameworks were valid. However, I was using Maven 2.2.1 and now I've changed the build to use Maven 3.0. Unfortunately, this generates a different error. Now, I am getting an error like the one below. The entire error sequence is more complex (i.e. there's much more after this), but this is where something seems to start going wrong.
    1) Error injecting: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping

Comment: Actually this is the very first item in the log tagged [ERROR] <br>

    [ERROR] Internal error: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors: